# Diagrams Elements Visibility

Tags: enterprise-architect

I would like to set visibility properties for all diagram elements in model (manually, not programmaticaly);

1. display diagram elements' notes
2. hide the elements type- make the type text invisible.

I tried to set the notes visible it via diagram properties- checked the Notes checkbox, but nothing happens:

[image]

Is it possible to set such properties for all diagrams at once? how?

Comment: With "element notes" you mean the diagram properties/Elements/Notes I guess? But what do you mean by "element type"?

Comment: @ThomasKilian, This is exactly what I mean. Re element type- didn't found yet how to do. Possible?

Comment: @ThomasKilian, I edit my post, please take a look.

Comment: Still don't know what "hide the elements type- make the type text invisible" means.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, and what about the notes problem?

Comment: Haven't you read my answer?

Comment: @ThomasKilian, Sure I've read. Isn't it possible to do it manually (not programmatically)???

Comment: Not for all diagrams at once. Only for single diagram. For all diagrams you need automation or a SQL.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, Well, how to do it for single diagram? It is not working the way I described. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen my reply here: http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1428995008

Comment: @ThomasKilian, Yes I did. I reply there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See p. 62 of my [Inside book](http://liquit.biz/brain/books.html). You need to modify `t_diagram.StyleEx`. It holds an attribute `ShowNotes=<v>;` where `<v>` is 0 or 1.

Re. your question about element type I still don't know what you mean. Can you post a picture?